# Angular 6 ng-select empty value when updated items

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select for my Angular 6 app and I have problem with updating [items] model.

I have dynamically adding inputs, where I'm using ng-select. Ng-selects options are dictionary items. But I can't repeat choosed values. So, when I'm adding new product I update ng-select options ([items]). But when I'm doing that, values added earlier are randomly cleared in view. Many times all are clearing (but values are still in form model).

Here is my ng-select:

```
<ng-select formControlName="productCode"
       [items]="avalaibleProductsDict"
       [selectOnTab]="true"
       bindLabel="name"
       bindValue="code"
       labelForId="productCode"
       (ngModelChange)="onSelect(i, product.code)"
       (focus)="setAvailableProductsDict(item.productType)"
       placeholder="Type a product"
       [required]="true">
```

and here function for updating available products:

```
  public setAvailableProductsDict(editingItem: ProductItemType): void {
let choosedProducts;

if (this.products && this.products.items) {
// map choosed products
  choosedProducts = this.products.items
    .map(
      item => {
        return {
          code: item.productType.code
        }
      });
} else {
  choosedProducts = [];
}


const availableProducts = _.differenceBy(this.productsDictionary, choosedProducts, 'code');
availableProducts.unshift(editingItem);
this.avalaibleProductsDict = _.tail(availableProducts);
```

}

My question is what I'm doing wrong? How to properly refresh available dictionary items to avoid blank values in view?

**UPDATE:**
When I have no changes in items model (here my dictionary) everything is fine, but when I updating dictionary, inputs are randomly cleared. I tried filter, but it also doesn't work. 
I found in documentation that "Ng-select component implements OnPush change detection which means the dirty checking checks for immutable data types. ".
Additionaly I found typeaheaf and searchFn in documentation. But I don't know how use it..